# Cant upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, upgrade, updates

I have 13.04 and I am trying to upgrade by cd to 14.04, because my update manager always says it cant find updates, but the option for upgrading is grey. what do I do?

Comment: You can't upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04 directly. Direct upgrades between LTS releases (12.04, 14.04) or successive releases (13.04, 13.10) are only supported. If you absolutely must upgrade, you'll have to first upgrade to 13.10 and then to 14.04. If you can reinstall or fresh install, then install 14.04.

Comment: Guys, this question is not a duplicate of "How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?" The answers on that question are for ways that have nothing to do with upgrading using a CD. The asker here is trying to upgrade using a CD but the Upgrade option is grayed out. The answers to the "possible duplicate" question will never answer his question, especially if he doesn't have internet.

Comment: @muru please post that as an answer, that is the correct answer.

Comment: @AlaaAli Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade an Ubuntu release only to its successor:

- For normal releases, this means the next release, whichever it may be. For 13.04, that would be 13.10.
- For LTS Releases, this has two meanings: the normal release following it, and the next LTS release. So Ubuntu 12.04 can be upgraded to 12.10 or 14.04.

Ubuntu 13.04 cannot be upgraded to 14.04 directly. That's why the installer has greyed out the upgrade option. It will have to be upgraded to 13.10, and then upgraded to 14.04.